# Modal window should only open once per day for each visitor

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cookies, modal-dialog

I created a modal windows that is shown to the website visitors after few seconds to notify something new.

[final result screenshot shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5OUa.png)

[And this is the temporary example web page](https://www.andreadd.it/appunti/polimi/appunti2.html)

The code I used is the following:

```
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
<h1 style="color:#395CC3">We need you !</h1><br>
<p>Lots of text...</p>
<div align="right"> <a href="mailto:contatti@andreadd.it" style="color: 
#395CC3; text-decoration:none">CONTATTACI !!!</a></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(event) {
  $('#ex1').modal({
    fadeDuration: 500,
    fadeDelay: 1.50,
    escapeClose: false,
  });
}, 10000);
</script>
```

The code is fully working but I want to put this code on all website pages.
I need that if the popup is shown to a visitor, then it will not show up anymore to that visitor for one day at least.

Can you help me to add the part of the code that can do that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localStorage to store the time it was last shown. [LocalStorage w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

```
let lastShown = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastShown')); //EDIT: Added parseInt
let maxTime = 1000; //ms (1 second)
//if lastShown is undefined or enough time has passed
if(!lastShown | lastShown + maxTime < Date.now()) { 

  //show it 
  //store the time to check next time the page is loaded
  localStorage.setItem('lastShown', Date.now());
}
```

Comment: Used max time 30 seconds but if I refresh the modal window doesn't show anymore!

<script>

let lastShown = localStorage.getItem('lastShown'); 
let maxTime = 30 * 1000; //ms (1 second)
//if lastShown is undefined or enough time has passed
if(!lastShown | lastShown + maxTime < Date.now()) { 


 if($(window).width() >= 768){
     setTimeout(function(event) {
       $('#ex1').modal({
         fadeDuration: 500,
        });
  }, 5000);
 }


  //store the time to check next time the page is loaded
  localStorage.setItem('lastShown', Date.now());
}
</script>

Comment: Oops, lastShown is a string so it doesn't add properly, add parseInt() to the lastShown. (I edited my answer to reflect this)